# Python Pyinstaller 3.1 Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, intel, anaconda

Hello fellow programmers, so I am having a spot of trouble getting this python .exe to function properly. I am using Anaconda 3 and the latest version of pyinstaller, and my code has nothing odd going on when I run it as a .py, but for the sake of distribution I need to have it as a ".exe". Whenever I try to run my .exe all I get is the error:

Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

and then it closes. Again, I am not having this problem if I run my python code in .py format from the same command window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Some details about your program would be nice, see [mcve]. Just in case you are using numpy, this might be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/34893933/5781248

Comment: This helped perfectly, also alternatively, I tried moving back to using Anaconda 2 (python 2.7), and with a few small tweaks to the code managed the same result. I will be adding it as an answer with more details shortly @J.J.Hakala

Answer (score 4):

The error means that the program couldn't find mkl library files under its library path, which is what you need to make it find.

I had the issue when running matplotlib scripts on windows with numpy+mkl, and I got it fixed by copying files that start with "mkl_" in `site-packages/numpy/core` to my python.exe root.

I'm not familiar with compiled python program but the idea should be the same. Since you had this error I assume you are using mkl version packages. You need to figure out where the .exe tries to load libraries from(could be the same path where the executable is located), and copy all the mkl dll's of any package there. Or there could be something like "compile options" that allows you to configure the path etc.

Hope it helps you.