# Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll on python executable

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, cx-freeze, intel-mkl

I'm trying to create an executable python  program that runs on windows without python being installed, for this I'm using cx_Freeze. But I get the following error: "Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll"

On my PC, which has python installed (miniconda3), I built the executable using cx_Freeze, and when I ran the executable I also would get "Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll". I fixed this by going to my python folder, Library\bin, and copied the mkl_intel_thread.dll file to where the executable is placed. The problem is, when moving the whole folder to another PC (without python installed), this error reappears, even though the mkl_intel_thread.dll is in the folder.

File that I want to distribute (plot.py):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [0, 2, 0]
plt.fill(a, b, 'b')
plt.show()
```

cx_Freeze setup file (setup.py):

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib
import numpy
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Miniconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Miniconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"


executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("plot.py")]


build_exe_options = {"includes":['numpy.core._methods',
        'numpy.lib.format', 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg']}

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "script",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    version = "0.0",
    description = "A basic example",
    executables = executables)
```

Comment: Which version of `cx_Freeze` are you using?

Comment: @jpeg The latest version on anaconda.org,  5.1.1

Comment: The issue causing `Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll` has been solved in cx_Freeze 6.7, see https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/739

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT:

1. Try to copy all files starting with `mkl` you find under `Library\bin` or `numpy\core` into the build folder, as well as `libiomp5md.dll`, see [Python Pyinstaller 3.1 Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35078548/8516269) and [cx_freeze converted GUI-app (tkinter) crashes after pressing plot-Button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34806650/8516269).

   Once you have found out which file(s) need(s) to be manually copied, you can let `cx_Freeze` include the necessary file(s) by using the `include_files` list of the `build_exe` options (see code snippet below). If necessary, you can use a tuple `(source, destination)` as item in the `include_files` list to let `cx_Freeze` copy a file from `source` to a specific `destination` into the build directory, see the `cx_Freeze`[documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe).
2. I see further potential problems in the setup script you've posted in your question:

   - include the whole `numpy` packages using the `packages` list of the `build_exe` options, it is easier and maybe safer
   - it is safer to dynamically find out the location of the TCL/TK DLLs
   - for `cx_Freeze` 5.1.1, the TCL/TK DLLs need to be included in a `lib` subdirectory of the build directory

In summary, try t o use

```
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['numpy'],
                     'includes': ['matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg'],
                     'include_files': [(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
                                        os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
                                       (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
                                        os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll'))
                                       # add here further files which need to be included as described in 1.
                                      ]}
```

in your setup script.

Comment: on my pc this will still give me "Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.". But again, I can copy the dll to the folder and it will work.I'll transfer to the other pc later but I suspect it will give the same error.

Comment: Try to copy all files starting with `mkl` you find under `Library\bin` or `numpy\core` into the build folder, as well as `libiomp5md.dll`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35078548/8516269) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34893933/8516269).

Comment: @Carlos Sounds great. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue affects cx_Freeze 6.1 or 6.2: the executable does not launch, either without error message or with

> INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. mkl_intel_thread.dll.
> Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

Configuration:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.5 installed from https://www.python.org/
- numpy 1.19.1+mkl installed with pip using wheel from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
- various python modules installed using pip

This is also observed with Python 3.6.8 or earlier versions of numpy such as e.g. 1.18.4+mkl or 1.19.0+mkl.

I've observed that cx_Freeze includes 3 DLLs `mkl_rt.dll`, `python38.dll`, and `vcruntime140.dll` in the subdirectory `lib\numpy\core` of the build directory, whereas the original installation does not contain any DLL in the subdirectory `site-packages\numpy\core` (all DLLs are in `site-packages\numpy\DLLs`). If I manually remove `mkl_rt.dll` from the subdirectory `lib\numpy\core` of the build directory after building the application with cx_Freeze, the issue disappears and the application works.

This solution can be implemented by adding the following code at the end of the `setup.py` script:

```py
numpy_core_dir = os.path.join(dist_dir, 'lib', 'numpy', 'core')
for file_name in os.listdir(numpy_core_dir):
    if file_name.lower().endswith('.dll'):
        file_path = os.path.join(numpy_core_dir, file_name)
        os.remove(file_path)
```

where `dist_dir` is the build directory generated by cx_Freeze (passed to the `build_exe` option).

Answer (score 0):

Just copy these four files in `cx_freeze` generated build folder

```
mkl_core.dll
mkl_def.dll
mkl_intel_thread.dll
mkl_mc3.dll
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, tt would be good if additional details are provided.

Comment: In my case removing `lib/numpy/core/mkl_rt.dll` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to find a solution to this by downgrading numpy==1.18.2 from numpy==1.19.1 when using cx_Freeze==6.5.3.