# cx_Freeze unable fo find mkl: MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze

I am struggling trying to generate a python executable on Windows 10. I have already tried the solution proposed  in [Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll on python executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337644/cannot-load-mkl-intel-thread-dll-on-python-executable) and many variations, but still getting the error.

My `setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

additional_mods = ["numpy", "pandas", "spacy"]
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
# buildOptions = dict(packages=[], excludes=[], includes=additional_mods)
buildOptions = dict(packages=additional_mods, excludes=[])

base = "Console"

executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base)]


setup(
    name="bpo",
    version="1.0",
    description="",
    options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
    executables=executables,
)
```

What could be happening? `mkl` is installed and I have copied its content to the `lib` path as the answer proposed.

I have also tried to set all these variables to 1, as specified in [Troubleshooting section](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed) of the anaconda docs without luck:

```
    CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE
    CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_DEBUG
    CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_NEVER_ADD_WINDOWS_DIRECTORY
    CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_NEVER_ADD_CWD
```

Comment: Which version of cx_Freeze are you using?

Comment: ` 5.1.1` the one that `conda install cx_freeze` installed, Its up to date I think

Comment: Yes it is the latest stable release, though it is quite old already.

Comment: Its working now!, it seems I was copying mkl_* files in the wrong path (inside `build/lib`) instead of `build/`. Now I am adding more missing modules to `additional_mods`

Comment: Sounds great. I was about to write a comment suggesting precisely this!

Comment: @jpeg Make it an answer if you want, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy the mkl_* dependencies to the `build` directory itself instead of the `build/lib`.

You can let cx_Freeze include the necessary file(s) by using the `include_files` list of the `build_exe` options.