# Pyinstaller does not properly include numpy in Mac bundle

Tags: python-3.x, macos, numpy, executable, pyinstaller

If I include numpy in my script the bundle application does not even open. However, if I run the application from the console everything is fine. So:

`pyinstaller -w myScript.spec`

with `import numpy as np` in one of the modules does not create a proper executable. However:

```
python3.7 myScript.py
```

runs without problems. Even more, if I comment the `import numpy as np` line the executable is created without problem. I have also used numpy in another console-only script without problems.

So, how can I make PyInstaller include numpy in the bundle app?

I checked the warn-myScript.txt file from PyInstaller and there are lots of modules from numpy.core that are not found, for example: numpy.core.sqrt.
But I have no idea where to find these modules.

I tried doing what j4n7 suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478526/pyinstaller-numpy-intel-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-mkl-intel-thread-dll), but it did not work.

I am using Python3.7, numpy 1.15.4 and PyInstaller 3.4

I installed Python from the Python web page and numpy and Pyinstaller using pip.

In a different computer I installed Python3.7 from homebrew and I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed miniconda and then created an environment with numpy 1.15.4, Pyinstaller 3.4 and python3.7.1. Within the environment, I can create the bundle app with no problem.

However, the bundle app goes to 600MB. I will start a new question regarding how to reduce the size of the bundle app.