# Intel MKL Error preventing me importing Scipy in Python

Tags: python, scipy, intel-mkl, intel-python

I am attempting to use scipy.integrate.solve_ivp, but the problem occurs with any import statement requiring scipy, including something as simple as:

```
import scipy
```

When I run this, I receive the following error:

```
INTEL MKL ERROR:
   dlopen(/Users/user/.conda/envs/nephron/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib, 9): 
   Library not loaded: @rpath/libiomp5.dylib
   Referenced from: /Users/user/.conda/envs/nephron/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib
   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/user/.conda/envs/nephron/bin/../lib/libiomp5.dylib: file too short.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.dylib.
```

I am using the Pycharm Community IDE (version 2019.2.3) with Anaconda plugin (but it happens even with I execute the script just in my terminal), and Python version 3.7.5 on a MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.  My package manager is conda 4.7.12.  EDIT: I have scipy version 1.3.1 installed.

I have not been able to find an explanation for this error on Stack or Google after a brief search, I have tried seeing if it was missing my installation of the package, but I looked upon the search paths being used by Python within Pycharm (as tested by running `python -V` in the terminal in Pycharm, indeed it occurs if I run it just through my normal Terminal), and indeed scipy was installed along one of the search paths.

EDIT:

I tried creating a new environment, removing the existing one, with `conda create -n nephron scipy`, this did not fix the problem.

Thank you to another user for adding a relevant tag.

Same problem appears to occur with other some other intel packages, such as numpy.

Comment: Which version of SciPy did you install?

Comment: 1.3.1, I've updated my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I installed seaborn after having installed months ago scipy. Scipy installed the mkl=2019 package and the newest version of seaborn required mkl=2020.

What I did was just deleting both scipy, seaborn and mkl=2019 and then I reinstalled them from conda.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause maybe [NumPy,SciPy is unable to load the correct MKL or Intel OpenMP runtime libraries](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed). This is almost always caused by one of two things:

1. The environment with NumPy or SciPy has not been activated.
2. Another software vendor has installed MKL or Intel OpenMP (libiomp5md.dll) files into the C:\Windows\System32 folder. These files are being loaded before Anaconda's and they're not compatible.

Try to set environment or do preload dll etc.

Here is Linux

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_def.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx2.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so:/opt/intel/lib/intel64_lin/libiomp5.so
```

In windows, setting env by mkl/bin/mklvars.bat intel64, then run your python in same environment

or in python to add the library manually sys.path.append(" your path to the library")  or [Pyinstaller numpy "Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478526/pyintaller-numpy-intel-mkl-)...

Comment: I had activated the conda environment, and as noted, I'm on a mac so there is no C:\Windows\System32, ultimately the solution was to completely purge Anaconda from my computer.