# Pyinstaller Intel MKL fatal error when running .exe file Python 2.7

Tags: python, executable, anaconda, pyinstaller

I have made a GUI application using wxpython and some other packages (matplotlib, pandas, numpy). I tried to compile this into a standalone executable. However, when I run the 'my_script.exe'  I get the following error in my command prompt:

> Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_avx2.dll or mkl_def.dll.

The versions I am using are:

- Anaconda 2.0.0 (Python 2.7) 64 bit
- Setuptools 19.2 (downgraded from 20.3 because of import error)

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: try this `conda install --yes mkl mkl-service` .

Comment: Do I need to rerun the compiler afterwards?

Comment: run it and then builld your `.exe` or search for `mkl_avx2.dll` & `mkl_def.dll` files and paste them in your `.exe` folder.

Comment: Rebuilding didn't work. But copying the mkl_avx2.dll file into the dist folder worked! Thank you for the help.

Comment: This might be related, http://stackoverflow.com/a/34893933/5781248

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `mkl_avx2.dll` & `mkl_def.dll` files and paste them in your `.exe`
 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Command in Command Prompt

```html
conda install --yes mkl mkl-service
```