# Print does not come out in Python + selenium console

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I have code in python and selenium, but when I created the executable the prints didn't print. On Pycharm the prints come out normally.

```
import os
import sys
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

config_name = 'geckodriver.exe'

# determine if application is a script file or frozen exe
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    application_path = os.path.splitdrive(application_path )
    print(application_path)
elif __file__:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    application_path = os.path.splitdrive(application_path)
    print(application_path)

config_path = os.path.join(application_path[0]+'/', config_name)
print(config_path)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=config_path)

options = Options()
options.headless = False  # Coloque True se quiser que não apareça o browser do FireFox
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
browser.maximize_window()
print("AGUARDE")
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: i think when you open the browser it is a blocking code does it prints out when you close the internet window?

Comment: No, when I close it it remains with nothing. In Pycharm even with the browser open it gives the print.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404800/cx-freeze-doesnt-print-to-console

Comment: I didn't quite understand, would I have to put those lines of code in mine?